# Magento 2 add youtube video to media gallery programmatically

Tags: magento2, gallery

I have some youtube video urls and the matching products. How can I add the videos to the media galleries of my products, as it would be added when I do this via the backend?

I tried using the class `ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagement`, but I would have to set a `content` value that is validated in the create method, but I have no idea to what value this should be set. I also tried to create the Entry and the VideoEntry over factories, but there I have to set a image file, otherwise I also get an exception. I don't have an image file, if I add the video via Backend it creates some placeholder image.

I just want the same behavior as when I go to the backend click `Add Video`, input URL, Title and Description and click Save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be a bug in the Api.

Looking at the Rest Api Documentation of the `catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1` Resource, the Image Content seems to be required while the Video content is optional:

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add YouTube Video to Magento 2.

**Generate YouTube API Key**

You need to generate YouTube API key from [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

**Integration of Youtube API key to Magento 2**

Then you have to integrate YouTube API to Magento 2 by going to Configuration section from Admin Panel

**Integration of Youtube Video URL to Product**

Now you have to add URL of YouTube videos by going to Product section from its Admin Panel.